# iOS: Add UIView below UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

if I try to add a view to the navigation bar in my custom UINavigationController with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.sv = (MyCustomView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        self.sv.frame = CGRectMake(self.navigationBar.frame.origin.x, self.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.navigationBar.frame.size.width, heightOfMyCustomView);
        [self.navigationBar addSubview:self.sv];
    }
```

and

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(viewController.view.frame.origin.x, viewController.view.frame.origin.y + heightOfMyCustomView, viewController.view.frame.size.width, viewController.view.frame.size.height - heightOfMyCustomView);
}
```

when I push a controller, the top part of the controller's view is hidden by my custom view I added to the navigation bar.
How can I put the controller's view down below my custom view?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck subclassing UINavigationBar and initializing your navigation controller with `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your custom UINavigationController init method assign delegate to itself, like this:

CustomeNavCtrl.m file:

```
@implementation CustomeNavCtrl

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    //Todo:viewController.view layout
    //Todo:send MyCustomView to back or something other you like.
}
```

CustomeNavCtrl.h file:

```
 @interface CustomeNavCtrl : UINavigationController<UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

 }
```

Comment: I solved setting in navigationController:didShowViewController:animated: the frame of the view controller's view. Thank you very much for putting me on the right way!

Comment: I don't think inheriting and overriding `UINavigationController` functions is a good idea, it's already a complex controller so you may add unnecessary complications and introduce errors.

Architecture with composition is general preferred over inheritance!

Answer (score -1):

I'd also suggest to take a look at UINavigationItem.titleView property, that gives you an ability to provide your view for navigation bar title area.

Comment: Won't be able to position to view below the `UINavigationBar`, since the `titleView` will be centered inside the nav bar. This is still useful to know, so I would add this information in the comment section but not as an answer.

Comment: This will work for adding a custom view *inside* the nav bar, which is what the question asked, however the title of the question asked about adding a view *below* the nav bar. OP should clarify what he was actually going for.